# String.Replace for "\"

Tags: c#

I can't seem to get this to work.  My cookie's string value has a leading and ending "\" in it.

Example cookie value would be:

```
"\"access_token=106447086076952%7C2.6l1KfdJFyvOgYuxgxn7__A__.3600.1282712400-1637262814%7CwUkJfvzS1CVSlg8H-DXOg94WlTA.&expires=1282712400&secret=y6LY_I_20sykbhU90hQKrg__&session_key=2.6l1KfdJFyvOgYuxgxn7__A__.3600.1282712400-1637262814&sig=6a62b60bb78fc51af"\"
```

I have no idea where this "\" is coming from but it's causing me all sorts of hell here and I need to get rid of it so that the HttpValueCollection doesn't get all screwed up with the "\".

I tried this with no luck, the value still shows "\":

```
facebookAuthCookie.Value = facebookAuthCookie.Value.Replace(@"\", string.Empty);
```

also tried

```
facebookAuthCookie.Value = facebookAuthCookie.Value.Replace("\\", string.Empty);
```

Comment: Think maybe it's not a backslash but rather an escaped quote? `\"`

Comment: you're right did not even see that

Comment: Click the spyglass icon to see the string in its original form.

Comment: I have seen a ton of these "unwanted backslash" questions recently.

Comment: did that, the spy glass is NOT showing the "\".  So that's what baffles me here.  Because when I try to access the cookie values, lets say facebookAuthCookie["access_token"]; it doesn't work but facebookAuthCookie["\"access_token"]; does

Comment: The spyglass won't show the slash, it will just show the double quote.

Comment: it shows this in the spyglass "access_token=106447086076952%7C2.B6wno18XLUFIX82gPD_Kkw__.3600.1282762800-1637262814%7C7wpMjj-6bSIEmroQEWbrLGV1qdc.&expires=1282762800&secret=Dsu0gaj4xwNUrMxTpE_S6Q__&session_key=2.B6wno18XLUFIX82gPD_Kkw__.3600.1282762800-1637262814&sig=d162b22a9ccbd424da4be97b3acb2273&uid=1637262814"

Comment: I just assumed that in the spyglass, the " was just ASP.NET'S way of starting off the string but that the real values being looked at were between ""...guess not and yes \" is an escaped quote..just didn't see it that way.  Now I am not able to remove it either with String.Replace

Comment: You cannot directly modify a cookie  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178194.aspx

Comment: That means that changing the value of a cookie in the Request object won't send it to the client (you have to use the Response object for that). It doesn't mean that the Value property isn't settable. The Value property is settable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you've presented it, it looks more like you have an escaped double quote in the string rather than a slash. So you probably want:

```
facebookAuthCookie.Value = facebookAuthCookie.Value.Replace("\"", string.Empty);
```

Comment: tried this but after this line, the value still shows "\"   facebookAuthCookie.Value.Replace("\"", string.Empty);

Comment: Well as you've described it that should work. Unless maybe the .Value property on facebookAuthCookie isn't actually getting the string to a new value internally ?

Comment: yea, that's what I'm researching, something is prohibiting me from applying replace to that value...

Answer (score 0):

I'm interpreting that cookie string as having a " at its start and end, not \.

Is it that the \ you're seeing is really just the escape char on the " character?